# Non-ascii characters in velocity templates are broken when displayed

Tags: unicode, velocity, non-ascii-characters

I have non-ascii chars in velocity template files. And when processed they are garbled.

The files are saved in UTF-8 encoding and response header contentType is also set to `text/html;charset=UTF-8`.

What else can be done?

Comment: What version of Velocity do you use?

Comment: Also, see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824901/handle-utf-8-datastring-velocity-struts

Comment: And the solution in question you've adviced doesn't work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the solution was to set up following velocity properties (part of Spring's bean def):

```
<entry key="input.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
<entry key="output.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
```